# "Minister for" and "Ministry of"

Tags: etymology, prepositions, terminology, government

In some British Commonwealth countries, e.g. [Singapore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Lee_Hsien_Loong_Cabinet#Cabinet), government ministries are named "Ministry of", as in "Ministry *of* Defence". However, the title of the minister in charge is "Minister for", as in "Minister *for* Defence". [Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_of_Australia#Current_cabinet) and [Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Government#Junior_Scottish_Ministers) are two other governments which use "Minister for".

In other countries, such as [Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_of_Canada#Current_cabinet), it is "Minister of". [New Zealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministers_in_the_New_Zealand_Government#Current_portfolios) is the most quirky, with an even mix of "Minister for" and "Minister of".

Why I know that semantically, as an earlier question answered, there is no difference in usage, does anyone know how the term "Minister for" came about? Why was it not consistently "Minister of" just like "Ministry of"?

Comment: "Ministry of Defence" is what that government department is called. "Minister of Defence" is what the head of that government department is called. When there's a "ministry," the head of that ministry is a "minister." As for "for" or "of," that's not really an oddity. "For" in that context means "on behalf of," so the "of" is in there. It's really just splitting hairs.

Comment: Britain has a mixture, too. There are no 'rules'. Did you think there should be?

Comment: I'm not asking about the rules or lack thereof. What I'm asking is whether there is any reason that "for" was used instead of "of" when the ministries themselves have always been consistently "of". We don't see "Ministry for xx" anywhere. Or is just one of those things that just is, without a reason. In any case, I think that for such official nomenclature, consistency is important.

Comment: The difference might be one of “minister **of** the department” vs “minister **for** the activity”.

Comment: Scotland may be slightly odd, because a "Minister for Defence" has only very limited devolved powers, as defence is something reserved to the UK Government in Westminster. While the research here is admirable, it's not really a question of *language* and we can't really answer why some states chose one and some the other.

Comment: We need a Ministry against Silly Walks.

Comment: I've heard that there's at least one cat detector van from the Ministry of Housinge as well.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, I seem to have found the answer. The term "minister" in the political sense of "a person appointed by a sovereign as the responsible head of a department" dates from the 1620s. The ministers of the crown, as they were called, were appointed by the sovereign to oversee, on his behalf, the duties and affairs they were appointed to, hence they were ministers (acting on behalf of the crown) for those duties or with responsibility for those duties. The word "minister" is also derived by the Latin root "minus" or "minor", meaning "servant" or "subordinate".

The term "ministry" itself, referring to a government department, only began to be used in 1916, with the earliest usage in a political sense (as opposed to a religious sense) in 1710. The ministry is a government department in charge of a certain sector of government, which is why it is a "ministry of", because their scope of work pertains to those duties, rather than acting on behalf of the crown to be responsible for those duties.